Redirect back to app after login Issue with Angular Auth OIDC Client in Ionic Capacitor
I’m currently developing an Ionic app using Capacitor, and I'm integrating authentication using the Angular Auth OIDC Client. The authentication flow works perfectly in the browser, but I’m facing an issue when redirecting back to the mobile application after a successful login. Instead of returning to the app, it remains stuck in the browser.
I’ve heard about deep linking as a potential solution, but I’m having trouble finding comprehensive documentation on how to implement it in my setup.
My questions are:

How can I properly set up deep linking in my Ionic app to handle
redirects from the browser back to the app?
Are there any specific configurations or steps required in the
Angular Auth OIDC Client to make this work?

I have tried modifying the capacitor.config.json file and adjusting the redirect URI in the OIDC configuration, but I’m still encountering issues. Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated!

by following the offical capacitor docs: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links.
